# Advantage of passing a Lambda expression instead of an Object

Tags: c#, lambda, fluentvalidation

I've been reviewing `FluentValidation` which is a nice validation library by the way but I noticed that they pass `LambdaExpression` in instead of an object property and I like to learn the advantage of this usage:

```
using FluentValidation;

public class CustomerValidator: AbstractValidator<Customer> {
  public CustomerValidator() {
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Surname).NotEmpty();
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Forename).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please specify a first name");
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Company).NotNull();
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Discount).NotEqual(0).When(customer => customer.HasDiscount);
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Address).Length(20, 250);
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Postcode).Must(BeAValidPostcode).WithMessage("Please specify a valid postcode");
  }

  private bool BeAValidPostcode(string postcode) {
    // custom postcode validating logic goes here
  }
}

Customer customer = new Customer();
CustomerValidator validator = new CustomerValidator();
ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(customer);

bool validationSucceeded = results.IsValid;
IList<ValidationFailure> failures = results.Errors;
```

As you can see `RuleFor(customer => customer.Surname).NotEmpty();` instead,  `RuleFor(customer.Surname).NotEmpty();` wouldn't be enough and clean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> instead, `RuleFor(customer.Surname).NotEmpty();` wouldn't be enough and clean?

No. Because at the time when you're calling `RuleFor`, you don't have a customer - therefore you can't access their surname.

As is usually the case with delegates, you're passing around *code to be executed at a later time*. The expression `customer.Surname` is an expression which would be *evaluated immediately* in the context of an existing `customer` variable.

Now if we had the mythical [infoof](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/21/in-foof-we-trust-a-dialogue.aspx) operator, we *could* do it without creating a delegate. We could potentially write something like:

```
RuleFor(infoof(Customer.Surname)).NotEmpty()
```

which would be lovely. The `RuleFor` method would take that property reference and evaluate it later against a given customer. Wonderful.

Unfortunately, we don't have that operator - so the easiest way of expressing the idea of "when you've got a customer, get hold of the `Surname` property" is to use a delegate. It's also very flexible, as it can work with (almost) any code you want to execute.

Comment: I see it now. Thanks for the prompt answer! +1

Comment: I have one thing in my mind if you don't mind. What if there was a instance variable defined in the `AbstractValidation<T>` class such as `T obj` and when calling `validate(customer)`, `T obj` could be set the `customer` instance and `RuleFor(obj.Name)` could be used.

Comment: Not really, because the whole point is to set up the validator *once* in the constructor, and have that apply to *multiple* instances over time. We want to call `RuleFor` once, not once per instance we validate.

Comment: But isn't that validating one instance at a time, I mean when saying `Validate` it gets the reference  in order to validate its properties. Wouldn't be the same passing in "instance variable"? Since `Validate` will switch the reference address of the instance field.

Comment: @DorianGray: You call `Validate`, you pass in the value, sure - but that's not when the `RuleFor` code runs. The *delegate* that you pass into the `RuleFor` call runs during the `Validate`. That's the point. You're setting up code to run later on.

Comment: OK I see now :) I was thining that they immediately run the delegate passed in. That's why I was thinking what the reason was but yeah it makes sense right now.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to pass `customer.SurName`, you would be pointing to the value of the `SurName` property of a specific `customer` instance.  Using a lambda function allows the validation logic to take a customer object when the validation logic is invoked, and then retrieve the `SurName` property of *that* customer.